# Prettify Js in php response

Tags: javascript, php, pretty-print

I have a response from php in the form of a minified script that changes a few variables from the server via DB calls etc. A sample response is like:

```
var primaryColor = '172983';var secondaryColor = '102429';var headerLogoImg = 'https://rb1.net/images/logo.png';var headerDefaultLogo = 1;function hexToRgb(hex) {    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);    return result ? parseInt(result[1], 16) + "," + parseInt(result[2], 16) + "," + parseInt(result[3], 16) : null;}
```

But I want the response sent in a pretty format like this:

```js
var primaryColor = '172983';
var secondaryColor = '102429';
var headerLogoImg = 'https://rb1.net/images/logo.png';
var headerDefaultLogo = 1;

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? parseInt(result[1], 16) + "," + parseInt(result[2], 16) + "," + parseInt(result[3], 16) : null;
}
```

How is it possible using print or echo or any inbuilt php functions?
I don't want to manually insert indentations and new line characters.

Comment: can I ask .... why do you need it pretty? if you need it pretty, why isn't it pretty in PHP in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript beautifier - PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275478/javascript-beautifier-php-script)

Comment: @Wazelin Could be a duplicate but the accepted answer there does not match my requirements.

Comment: @JaromandaX How do i do it pretty in Php? that's the question! I don't need it pretty as such.. would be good if it was pretty as this is a part of an integration flow..